# Ubuntu openssl version upgrade

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, openssl

I upgraded openssl version upgrade from OpenSSL/1.0.1f to OpenSSL 1.1.0h, But it showing as apache2 is working with older version.

Apache Version :- Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.0.1f

Can any one please provide solution to active 1.1.0h instead of 1.0.1f

Comment: Did you restart apache2?

Comment: yes....i done that